# Java 8 requireNonNull method with supplier parameter performance

Tags: java, string, object, java-8, null-check

Method [Objects.requireNonNull](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-java.util.function.Supplier-) with `Supplier` added in Java 8, but I'm not sure what's the performance improvement declared:

> While this may confer a **performance advantage in the non-null case**, when deciding to call this method care should be taken that the costs of creating the **message supplier are less than the cost of just creating the string message directly.**

Method with String ignores parameter if not null:

```
public static <T> T requireNonNull(T obj, String message) {
    if (obj == null)
        throw new NullPointerException(message);
    return obj;
}
```

I found [JDK-8011800 : Add java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(T, Supplier)](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8011800)

> In JDK 7, java.util.Objects included several methods to check for null, including one that took a message to return if a null was found. With lambdas in JDK 8, another variant to include is a requireNonNull method which takes a string supplier instead of a string. That why **the cost of creating the string message can be avoided for the non-null case. Note that the lambda capture can have a nonzero cost though.**

With comment indicate no performance impact:

> The non-zero capture cost does worry me. **I am concerned that it will frequently erase any advantage of using a Supplier.**
> 09-04-2013

I found other questions, but not referring to (why) sending String parameter have performance costs

Is it specific for lambda expressions/stream usage?

Comment: *probably* meant for the case that creating the String is not trivial (performance related) like having to call an *expensive* method - based on the last part of "... message supplier are less than the cost of just creating the string message directly"

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger you mean that the string need to be built using StringBuilder for example? can you extend to an answer?

Comment: Think of a complex error message including information on the state of the program

Comment: `StringBuilder` (or `+` concatenation), `String.format` and as I added to my comment, calling some other methods ("*this method allows creation of the message to be deferred until after the null check is made*") - if the tested object is not null, there is no need to *create* the message, but if the method gets the message as string, it is already done

Comment: Precisely the part in the documentation that hints the same: *Unlike the method `requireNonNull(Object, String)`, this method allows the **creation of the message to be deferred until after the null check is made***

Comment: @user7294900 can you try to explain what is unclear to you? Creating a `Supplier` has a certain performance cost, as has creating a `String`. Creating a simple String can be "cheaper" than creating a `Supplier`. But if creating the String involves expensive operations for some reason and the assumption is that `null` rarely occurs, it can be better to create the supplier, and only invoke those expensive operations when they are really needed.

Comment: That said, I've never found a need to use the Supplier-overload so far. The typical use-case is to perform parameter validation of things that should never be null, and a very concise constant message is usually enough to cover these cases.

Comment: @Hulk yes, it seems very specific cases probably found in java 8 development

Comment: If examples involving string concatenation or using a formatter don’t convince you, think loading messages from a resource bundle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider this, where `generateString` does a lot of stuff in order to generate a string from `someParam`:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(obj, generateString(someParam));
```

Arguments are evaluated eagerly in Java, which means that `generateString` will be evaluated before `requireNonNull` is called. It is therefore computed regardless of whether `obj` is null or not.

You can fix this problem by changing it to this:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(obj, () -> generateString(someParam));
```

In this case, `generateString` will only be called if `obj` actually was null. This is more efficient when `generateString` is more expensive than creating the `Supplier`-object.

You should just use the normal non-lambda method if your String parameter is just a literal, like:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(obj, "obj was null!");
```

Comment: Is there a way to decide the balance between expense of creating the string vs expense of creating the supplier?